# Need Magento one menu item not clickable

Tags: php, magento

I want one menu item in navigation not clickable. I have found help where I can make the whole navigation not clickable but I need only one item not clickable and its drop down categories should be click able.

Here is website link: http://www.thehimalaya-ss.com/site/. I want menu item named as "shop" not clickable and its drop down should be click able.

Answer (score 2):

using jquery remove a tag value:

```
<script>
    jQuery('#nav .in-category-node-12').removeAttr("href");
</script>
```

Add this script on your head file or footer file use for last load this script.

[image]
[image]

Comment: see the image i have fixed but u can have add time misstack.

Comment: Try wrapping it on onready listener.  You may be calling it before the item exists.

Comment: I have added it at the end of head.phtml... inside <script> of course. :)

Comment: Cant you just replace the href of shop tab with "#" for now?